# How to smooth bezier solid

Tags: bezier-curves

I've made this custom lower body of a five (5) using 4 bezier curves, converted the curves into mesh and applied subdivision surface. How to smooth these faces? Shade smooth doesn't look good even with recalculated normals.
[image: This is the solid made of four bezier curves]

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't look good? Have enabled the Auto Smooth option in the Object Data panel > Normals? If it still doesn't work please share your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEFORE you convert the curve to mesh, subdivide the bezier curve once or twice, and dail up the U resolution to suit your needs. If the curve is twisting, select a point and press ctrl+T to correct the twist. Resolution of 0 will give you a square cross section. It should look smooth in both flat and smooth shading.

[image: Here you can see how to do it]